# Llenar arreglo char con caracteres de uno más grande en ASSEMBLY IA32

Tags: c, ensamblador, programación-bajo-nivel

Estoy tratando de hacer la traducción de un código que hice en C a assembly IA32:

```
int i=0;
char s[3]; 
char c[n];

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    s[i] = c[i];
}
```

`n` es una variable de tipo entero que recibe una entrada del usuario, para el momento en que este `for` se está ejecutando "c" ya está lleno de caracteres, quiero, como se puede ver, meter en "s" los primeros tres caracteres de c.
Esto lo implementé así en assembly:

```
for:
    cmpl $3,%eax
    jge endfor
    movb c(%eax),%ecx
    movb %ecx,s(%eax)
    incl %eax
    jmp for

endfor:
    movl  $0,%eax
    pushl %eax
    pushl $s
    pushl $is
    call printf
    addl $8,%ebp
    popl %eax

is: .asciz "%s"
.comm c,500,1
.comm s,500,1
```

El problema es que al ejecutar este código no me imprime nada, como si no el arreglo no se hubiese llenado, he intentado bastante cosas y nada me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 1):

**Para este código similar al tuyo:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  int i=0;
  char s[4];
  s[3] = '\0';
  char c[3] = {'1','2','3'};   
  for(i=0;i<3;i++){
      s[i]=c[i];
  }

  printf("%s",s);
  return 0;
}
```

**Este sería su emsamblador:**

```
.LC0:
        .string "%s"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 32
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-13], 0
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-32], 49
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-31], 50
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-30], 51
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
.L3:
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 2
        jg      .L2
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cdqe
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rbp-32+rax]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cdqe
        mov     BYTE PTR [rbp-16+rax], dl
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        lea     rax, [rbp-16]
        mov     rsi, rax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

Comment: Lo ideal sería poner un ensamblador propio... No el que genera el compilador de c. Por otro lado no le estás ayudando a encontrar el motivo por el que no se le imprimen los valores